# SMTP C++ linux using sockets how to implement SSL?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, smtp

I have a problem with smtp.cpp program in C++ on linux sockets.When i compile it
I have to input the following (domain account@domain recipient@domain attachment and prepare the message) and after filling them the smtp should send an email to
recipient@domain but it keeps saying Message not sent.
The smtp is without ssl because i want to use only port25 for sending emails and testing.
But i cant use it on Port25 i need to implement SSL (port 465)on sockets does anyone know how to do that so the smtp will work ?
Please help

smtp.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>//s_port , h_name,h_addrtype
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


#define buf_size 1024
#define chunk_size 54 //rozmiar porcji
void err(const char *where) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error in %s: %d\n", where, errno);
    exit(1);
}
string base64_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

string BOUNDARY_TEXT = "BOUNDARY_TEXT";
string CRLF = "\r\n";//CR, wartość ASCII równa 13, '\r') + line feed (LF, wartość ASCII 10, '\n'
// OZNACZA koniec bieżącej linii

string getFormatTime()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char bufer[80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    strftime (bufer, 80, "Date: %a, %d %B %Y %T %z", timeinfo);//Format time as string
    string time(bufer);
    return time;
}

string getHeader(string login, string recipient, string subject, vector<string> &attachments)
{
    stringstream header;
    // Date: <SP> <dd> <SP> <mon> <SP> <yy> <SP> <hh> ":" <mm> ":" <ss> <SP> <zone> <CRLF>
    header << getFormatTime() << CRLF;
    // From: <SP> <sender>  <SP> "<" <sender-email> ">" <CRLF>
    header << "From: <" << login << ">" << CRLF;
    // X-Mailer: <SP> <xmailer-app> <CRLF>
    header << "X-Mailer: Poster" << CRLF;
    // Reply-To: <SP> <reverse-path> <CRLF>
    // X-Priority: <SP> <number> <CRLF>
    header << "X-Priority: 3 (Normal)" << CRLF;
    // To: <SP> <remote-user-mail> <CRLF>
    header << "To: <" << recipient << ">" << CRLF;
    // Cc: <SP> <remote-user-mail> <CRLF>
    // Bcc: <SP> <remote-user-mail> <CRLF>
    // Subject: <SP> <subject-text> <CRLF>
    header << "Subject: " << subject << CRLF;
    // MIME-Version: <SP> 1.0 <CRLF>
    header << "MIME-Version: 1.0" << CRLF;

    if(attachments.size() == 0)
    {
     //Content-Type POLE TYPU ZAWARTOŚCI
       // uzywane jest do wskazania klientowi poczty zarówno uzytego sposobu kodowania 
       //wiadomosci, jak i ewentualnie sposobu postepowania z odebrana wiadomoscia.
        header << "Content-type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII" << CRLF;
        //Content-Transfer-Encoding informuje, w jaki sposob traktuje sie znaki o kodach wiekszych od 127
        header << "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" << CRLF;
        header << CRLF;
    }
    else
    {
    //wiadomosc zawiera kilka rozlacznych czesci 
  //Tekst w 'boundary' bedzie wykorzystywany jako znacznik rozdzielajacy kazdy ze skladnikow wiadomosci
        header << "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"";
        header << BOUNDARY_TEXT << "\"" << CRLF;
        header << "--" << BOUNDARY_TEXT << CRLF;
        header << "Content-type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII" << CRLF;
        header << "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" << CRLF;
        header << CRLF;
    }
    return header.str();
}
//kodowanie wiadomosci
string encode(char* chunk, int length)
{
    string ostr = "";
    static long long out_size = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i+=3)
    {
        unsigned char s1 = chunk[i];
        //Gott!!! FIXED
        unsigned char s2 = (length > 1) ? chunk[i+1] : 0;
        unsigned char s3 = (length > 2) ? chunk[i+2] : 0;

        int n = s1;
        n <<= 8;
        n |= s2;
        n <<= 8;
        n |= s3;

        int p1 = static_cast<int>(n & 0x3f);
        n >>= 6;
        int p2 = static_cast<int>(n & 0x3f);
        n >>= 6;
        int p3 = static_cast<int>(n & 0x3f);
        n >>= 6;
        int p4 = static_cast<int>(n & 0x3f);

        ostr += base64_chars[p4];
        ostr += base64_chars[p3];

        if(length - i >= 3)
        {
            ostr += base64_chars[p2];
            ostr += base64_chars[p1];
        }
        if(length - i == 2)
        {
            ostr += base64_chars[p2];
            ostr += '=';
        }
        if(length - i == 1)
        {
            ostr += '=';
            ostr += '=';
        }

        out_size += 4;
    }
    return ostr;
}
/*
Funkcja getline jest preferowana metoda czytania linii tekstu z gniazda, 
w tym standardowych wejscia.Pobiera linie danych z gniazda socket
*/
static int getLine (int socket, char *line, int length)
{
    //memset(line, '\0', buf_size);
    char ch;
    int bytes = 0;

    while (read(socket, &ch, 1) > 0)
    {
        *line++ = ch;
        bytes++;
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            *line = 0;
            return bytes;
        }

        if (bytes == length - 1)
        {
            *line = 0;
            return bytes;
        }
    }
    *line = 0;
    err("problem");
    return -1;
}
//wysylanie
void send(int sock, string command)
{
    write(sock, command.c_str(), command.length());
}
//odbior
int receive(int sock)
{
    char buf[buf_size];
    char code[3];
    getLine(sock, buf, buf_size);
    strncpy(code, buf, 3);
    puts(buf);
    return atoi(code);;//Convert string to integer
}
//wysyla plik
void sendFile(int sock, string file_to_send)
{
    //ifstream - Stream class to read from files
    //Construct object and optionally open file
    ifstream is(file_to_send.c_str(), ifstream::binary);
    string out = "";

    if (is) 
    {
        is.seekg(0, is.end);//Set position in input sequence
        is.seekg(0, is.beg);

        char chunk[chunk_size];
        while(!is.eof())
        {
            is.read(chunk, chunk_size);
            send(sock, encode(chunk, is.gcount()) + CRLF);
        }
        is.close();
    }
}
//wysylanie maila
int sendMail(int sock, char* account_login, char* passwd, string recipient, string subject, string msg, vector<string> &attachments)
{
    string header;

    send(sock, "helo domain" + CRLF);
    if(receive(sock) != 250)
    err("domain problem");
        return -1;

    send(sock, "auth login" + CRLF);
    if(receive(sock) != 334)
    err("auth login problem");
        return -2;
    //zakodowany login
    send(sock, encode(account_login, strlen(account_login)) + CRLF); 
    if(receive(sock) != 334)
    err("encoding login problem");
        return -3;

    send(sock, encode(passwd, strlen(passwd)) + CRLF);
    if(receive(sock) != 235)
    err("encoding password problem");
        return -4;

    string login(account_login);
    send(sock, "mail from:" + login + CRLF);
    if(receive(sock) != 250)
    err("account-domain problem");
        return -5;

    send(sock, "rcpt to:" + recipient + CRLF);
    if(receive(sock) != 250)
    err("recipient problem");
        return -6;

    send(sock, "data" + CRLF);
    if(receive(sock) != 354)
    err("data problem");
        return -7;

    header = getHeader(login, recipient, subject, attachments);
    send(sock, header);

    if(msg.size() == 0)
        send(sock, " " + CRLF);
    else
        send(sock, msg + CRLF);

    vector<string>::iterator temp = attachments.begin();
    while(++temp != attachments.end())
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "--" << BOUNDARY_TEXT <<
        ss << "Content-Type: application/x-msdownload; name=\"";
        ss << basename(static_cast<string>(*temp).c_str());
        ss << "\"" << CRLF;
        //sposob kodowania informacji binarnej
        ss << "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" << CRLF;
        //pole Content-Disposition identyfikuje te czesc wiadomosci jako załacznik
        ss << "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"";
        ss << basename(static_cast<string>(*temp).c_str());
        ss << "\"" << CRLF;
        ss << CRLF;
        send(sock, ss.str());
        cout << *temp << endl;

        sendFile(sock, *temp);
    }

    if(attachments.size() > 0)
    {
        send(sock, CRLF);
        send(sock, "--" + BOUNDARY_TEXT + "--" + CRLF);
    }
//Klient musi poprawnie obsługiwać pojawienie się linii wiadomości 
//zaczynającej się od kropki lub kropek.
    // <CRLF> . <CRLF>
    send(sock, CRLF + "." + CRLF);
    if(receive(sock) != 250)
    err(". problem");
        return -8;

    send(sock, "quit" + CRLF);
    if(receive(sock) != 250)
    err("quit problem");
        return -9;
    return 0;
}
/*
void err(const char *where) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error in %s: %d\n", where, errno);
    exit(1);
}
*/
int connect(char* server, const char* proto)
{
    //adres serwera np poczta.o2.pl
    char *remote = server; 
    //struktura zwiazana z serwerem
    struct servent *sent;
    //struktura zwiazana z nazwa protokolu
    struct protoent *pent;
    int  port;
    int  sock;
    int  result;
    //struct in_addr {in_addr_t s_addr lub ipadr;};
    in_addr_t ipadr;
    //struktura obslugujaca adresowe internetowe
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    //struktura zwiazana z nazwa hosta
    struct hostent *hent;

    char buf[buf_size];
    char filename[30];
     //łańcuch zawierający nazwę usługi (np. ”pop3”,"http" itp)
   //łańcuch zawierający nazwę protokołu (”tcp”, ”udp”, ”ip”)
    sent = getservbyname(proto, "tcp");
    if(sent == NULL)
        err("getservbyname");
    port = sent->s_port;
    pent = getprotobyname("tcp");
    if(pent == NULL)
        err("getprotobyname");
        //nazwa hosta w postaci łańcucha (symboliczna lub adres IP)
    hent = gethostbyname(remote);
    printf("Host: %s\n", hent->h_name);
    printf("IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)hent->h_addr)));
    //struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = port;
    addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)hent->h_addr);
    //Sets the first 8 bytes of the block of memory pointed by sin_zero to the specified value \0
    memset(addr.sin_zero, '\0', 8);
    //AF_INET - internet domain sockets|SOCK_STREAM - Byte-stream socket,
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, pent->p_proto);
    if(sock < 0)
        err("socket");
    result = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if(result < 0)
        err("connect");

    getLine(sock, buf, buf_size);
    puts(buf);

    return sock;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 4)
    {
        cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << ": domain account@domain recipient@domain [attachment, attachment, ...]" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    char* server = argv[1];
    char* account_login = argv[2];
    string recipient(argv[3]);
    string subject = "";
    string msg = "";
    vector<string> attachments;

    for(int i = 3; i < argc; i++)
    {
        string filename(argv[i]);
        attachments.push_back(filename);
    }

    cout << "Preparing message..." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter your topic: " << endl;
    getline(cin, subject);
    cout << "Enter your message here <EOF>" << endl;

    char tempChar;
    while (!cin.eof())
    {
        cin.get(tempChar);
        msg += tempChar;
    }
    //getpass - ukrywa nam haslo podczas wprowadzania go na ekranie
    char* passwd = (char*)(intptr_t)getpass("Enter password: ");

    int sock = connect(server, "smtp");
    if(sendMail(sock, account_login, passwd, recipient, subject, msg, attachments) != 0)
        cout`enter code here` << "Message not sent." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Message has been sent successfully." << endl;

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Letting `sendMail()` return the same error code for dozens of different errors and not printing out any error messages at all is very unhelpful for debugging. Fix `sendMail()` accordingly. Afterwards you will have a clue where it breaks and probably why it breaks. Similar issues apply to your other functions. There are lots of places where you just ignore the return code. Fix this, too. Looking at `errno` will help.

Comment: ./smtp poczta.o2.pl kalamata1991@o2.pl erotas@amorki.pl lol.txt
Preparing message...

Enter your topic: 
fgfgfg
Enter your message here <EOF>
gfgfgfgf
gfgf
  ssfs
Enter password: 
Host: poczta.o2.pl
IP: 193.17.41.99
220 poczta.o2.pl ESMTP Wita

250 poczta.o2.pl

error in domain problem: 0
Iam writing the correct domain for sure.I dont know why it gives an error

Comment: Use a library like [vmime](http://www.vmime.org/) ... and compile with `g++ -Wall -g` then use a debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: I have to use only libraries and classes offered by sockets .I cant use other libraries or classes

Comment: So the error occurs at `receive()`? In that case check what the server returned (possibly an error message?) and which error code occured. Additionally I wouldn't call `getline()` on a socket, use `read()` instead and check its return code.